# How can I define a global property in rhino?

Tags: javascript, java, rhino

I'm embedding Rhino in Java and I want to create a global property with a getter and setter. This non-global property definition works:

```
var testObj = {};
Object.defineProperty(testObj, 'testPropName', {
  set: function(value) { print('setter called w/' + value); }
});
```

If I try it w/ the global "this" object it throws an error:

```
Object.defineProperty(this, 'testPropName', {
  set: function(value) { print('setter called w/' + value); }
});
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Expected argument of type object, but instead had type object (#1) in  at line number 1
```

Creating it from the Java-side would be fine too, but I've had no luck with that either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution from the Java side...

```
public class MyCustomBindings extends SimpleBindings {

@Override
public Object put(String name, Object value) {
  Object result = super.put(name, value);
  // "setter" logic
  return result;
}

@Override
public Object get(Object key) {
  // "getter" logic
  return super.get(key);
}
```

and elsewhere...

```
ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
MyCustomBindings bindings = new MyCustomBindings();
engine.getContext().setBindings(bindings, ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
```